# What is the convention for using results of theorems left as exercise in the text?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

I'm working on an exam, and have a solid proof for one of the problems, but it's reliant on a number of theorems left exercises in the textbook which were not assigned as coursework.  What, if any convention is there for using those results in later proofs?

Comment: This would be a good question to ask your instructor.

Comment: I already have, waiting on a reply.  I was just curious to see if there was some established rule here.

Comment: Since you basically ask for an opinion, here's mine: I'd expect to see evidence that the exercises were actually solved by you. That is: at least an outline of the solution if not a full proof, or a reference to a different text where proofs are given.

Comment: A long time ago, I took a take-home exam (in a graduate course) in which one question was of the form "Prove or disprove: A".  One of my fellow students turned in an answer which said "Problem x.yz of our textbook asks us to prove or disprove B.  Assuming B is true, the following is a proof that A is true. .....  Assuming B is false, the following is a proof that A is false."  He got extra credit (and an A+ grade) for creativity.

Comment: you should probably prove it, and since you asked your instructor, s/he probably assumes you havent proven it (else you would have just included a proof) and s/he will make you prove it.